# Codes to be inserted to Session_End block to notify user timeout or redirect

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sessionend

How to display a popup window in C# that tell the user the session has expired? I am thinking about an analogy in JavaScript `alert "Your session has expired";`. Is there such analogy in C#?

Alternative solution is to direct my user to Default.aspx page. I have seen many lines of code using Google, but none of them work in `protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) {}` block. I am looking for lines of code that can be inserted into `Session_End` block. Otherwise, I would have to insert the codes into over 200 .aspx pages.

I also know that HTTP is stateless and `Response.Redirect()` doesn't work when the `Session_End()` fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply stated, if it reached `Session_End` it's too late to notify the client. At that point, everything is gone.

You mention modifying 200 pages, but if you're using a Master Page (which I hope you would be), that would be the most elegant place to put a timeout warning.

Comment: Is there an event I can write code to notify the user the session is about to end? I have seen popup window say "You have been inactive for 15 minutes. Click OK now to remain logged in or Cancel to end your session" when checking balance with financial institutions.
A timer would also do the job. The ultimate goal is to let the user know so they won't enter data into form, hitting update button, and learn that the session has ended which mean the data didn't save and they have to re-type.

Comment: That's needs to be done on the page, and is usually a set timeout based on the session's expiration time.